# _D3DVECTOR' : 'struct' type redefinition

Tags: c++

have this error. What is wrong? Thanks for any reply

Error   36  error C2011: '_D3DVECTOR' : 'struct' type redefinition  \Renderer.h

Error   37  error C2504: '_D3DVECTOR' : base class undefined    \Renderer.h

This is Render.h

```
#include <D3D11.h> 
#include <d3dx11.h> 
#include <DXErr.h> 
#include <D3DX11async.h> 
#include <D3Dcompiler.h> 
#include <D3dx11effect.h> 
#include <D3D11Shader.h> 
#include "FW1FontWrapper.h" 

#ifndef _D3DVECTOR 
ERROR here> typedef struct _D3DVECTOR {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} D3DVECTOR;
#endif 

#ifndef D3DXVECTOR3 
typedef struct D3DXVECTOR3 : public D3DVECTOR
ERROR here> {
public:
    D3DXVECTOR3() {};
    D3DXVECTOR3(CONST FLOAT *);
    D3DXVECTOR3(CONST D3DVECTOR&);
    D3DXVECTOR3(CONST D3DXFLOAT16 *);
    D3DXVECTOR3(FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT z);

    // casting 
    operator FLOAT* ();
    operator CONST FLOAT* () const;

    // assignment operators 
    D3DXVECTOR3& operator += (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&);
    D3DXVECTOR3& operator -= (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&);
    D3DXVECTOR3& operator *= (FLOAT);
    D3DXVECTOR3& operator /= (FLOAT);

    // unary operators 
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator + () const;
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator - () const;

    // binary operators 
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator + (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&) const;
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator - (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&) const;
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator * (FLOAT) const;
    D3DXVECTOR3 operator / (FLOAT) const;

    friend D3DXVECTOR3 operator * (FLOAT, CONST struct D3DXVECTOR3&);

    BOOL operator == (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&) const;
    BOOL operator != (CONST D3DXVECTOR3&) const;

} D3DXVECTOR3, *LPD3DXVECTOR3;
#endif
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for include guards? it seems you're including this c++ header file more than once and then the error.

Comment: Is this `Renderer.h` and if so, which line does each error occur on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `#ifndef` cannot be used to detect structure tags or typedefs.  `#ifndef` is only useful for determining whether a macro (declared with `#define`) exists.

For example the following code will generate two errors, "hello" and "world".

```
typedef struct _D3DVECTOR {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} D3DVECTOR;

#ifndef _D3DVECTOR
#error hello
#endif

#ifndef D3DVECTOR
#error world
#endif
```

Comment: But now i have redifinition - 'D3DVECTOR' : redefinition; different basic types. Sorry i am new at C++

Comment: Cleaned them, still same error( now my include are              #include "FW1FontWrapper.h" 
#include <d3dx11.h> 
#include <D3dx11effect.h>

Comment: This isn't a chat room. It's not a place for a conversation where you go through all your errors one at a time. More broadly, Stack Overflow is not a helpdesk. Do you have a tutor or friend who can mentor you through these faults?

Comment: You my friends) Ye, sorry for this. I understand)